# The matrix calculation in exponentionwhy is $-x^T\Lambda^{-1}m-m^T\Lambda^{-1}x=-2m^T\Lambda^{-1}x$?

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, matrix-calculus

$x,m $ and $ \Lambda$ are all matrix,$\Lambda$ is covariance matrix

$e^{\frac{-(x-m)^T\Lambda ^{-1}(x-m)}{2}} \times e^{ju^Tx}$

its exponential part calculation is

$\frac{-(x^T \Lambda^{-1}x-x^T\Lambda^{-1}m-m^T\Lambda^{-1}x+m^T\Lambda^{-1}m)+2ju^Tx}{2}$

=$\frac{-(x^T \Lambda^{-1}x-2m^T\Lambda^{-1}x+m^T\Lambda^{-1}m)+2ju^Tx}{2}$

=$\frac{-(x-(m+j\Lambda u))^T\Lambda^{-1}(x-(m+j\Lambda u))+jm^Tu-\frac{1}{2}u^T\Lambda u}{2}$

1.For the first and second formula,why is  $-x^T\Lambda^{-1}m-m^T\Lambda^{-1}x=-2m^T\Lambda^{-1}x$?

2.For the second and third formula,how does the second formula become to third formula?can someone teach me more detail?

Comment: $\Lambda$ not $\wedge$

Comment: if $x,m$ are column vectors, that is matrices of size $n$ by $1,$ then you just need that a 1 by 1 matrix is its own transpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $\Lambda$ is symmetric, then $x^\top \Lambda^{-1} m = m^\top \Lambda^{-1} x$.
2. Take the first term in the third formula and expand it. (e.g. $(a+b)^\top\Lambda^{-1}(a+b) = a^\top \Lambda^{-1} a + 2 a^\top \Lambda^{-1} b + b^\top \Lambda^{-1} b$ etc.)